# How to use terminal command in vifm

Tags: vifm

I want to run terminal command in vifm

For example, Can I execute `code .` command in vifm?

Comment: @Quasímodo In my terminal, ‘code .’ to open vscode in the current dir

Comment: @Quasímodo is your comment above worthy of being turned into a proper Answer?

Comment: @stefancho can you [edit] your question to address the confusion above? Thank you!

Comment: I edit a question, sorry for two mixed question topics